# How to change text style in qgis2threejs?

Tags: qgis2threejs

Is there any possibility to change text style for names of places in QGIS 2 three js plugin? That's my result: black font with white outline, [image]while in layer style properties I have for this label just white font color.[image]

Comment: Not an answer but a question (I don't have enough rep to just comment). What are you using as your imagery layer? I'm working on a project involving qgis2threejs and a few collada models. But when I use google satellite imagery via the openlayers plugin it breaks the model scale.

Comment: I use satellite image generated from here:https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/sentinel-playground/  and tie it to the map with Georeferencer which is in Raster menu

Answer (score 3):

Qgis2threejs uses HTML div elements of the class "label" for its labels. You can set their style in your HTML or related stylesheets like

```
div.label {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(255, 0, 255, 1);
}
```

I don't think that label styles from QGIS are transferred to the export yet.

Comment: You're welcome! Have fun :)